# Kiwi stub and return issue

Tags: ios, stubbing, kiwi

I want to test the creation of my object using Kiwi. Consider construction like this

> id objectOne = [ObjectOne objectWithAnotherObject:objectTwo];

Inside of this static method I set up my objectOne from objectTwo, which has defined enum/type property.

my Kiwi test looks like this.

> ObjectTwo *objectTwo = [ObjectTwo mock];
>
> [objectTwo stub:@selector(type) andReturn:theValue(typeOne)];
>
> id objectOne = [ObjectOne objectWithAnotherObject:objectTwo];

The problem i'm facing with this right now is the exception:

> [NSException raise:@"KWStubException" format:@"wrapped stub value type (%s) could not be converted to the target type (%s)", [self.value objCType], objCType];

Does it mean, that Kiwi wasn't able to convert object theValue(typeOne) back to enum value?

Im using XCODE 6 and the latest Kiwi release

Comment: how is typeOne defined btw?

Comment: it's defined similar to this -> enum EType { ETypeOne = 0 };

Comment: I think I also had this problem once, is it the same if instead of theValue(typeOne) you directly write @(typeOne) ?

Comment: I posted it as an answer so that people don't have to go through the comments. Feel free to mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution, type `@(typeOne)` instead of `theValue(typeOne)`